# Moving image across the screen

Tags: javascript

Am a beginner in html5 and am facing this problem in a simple program to move an image across the screen. Its a simple pacman program where i used two images. One is a pacman with mouth open and other with mouth closed When i tried to mov it across the screen towards right and then it has to return to its initial position. It tried many ways but none works. It moves only once for a step and for the next step it is static. It will be really helpful if anyone could solve this

```
<html>
<head>
<SCRIPT>
    var timer = setInterval(Run,500);
    flag = 1;
    function Run(){
    img1 = document.getElementById("PacMan");
    var init=0;
    var x = 0; 
    var dest_x = 800;  
    var interval = 10; 
    if(x<dest_x) 
        x = x + interval; 
        img1.style.left = x+"px";
    if (x+interval < dest_x)
        img1.style.left = init+"px";
    if(flag ==1){
        img1.src = "PacMan2.png";
        flag=0;

    }
    else {
        img1.src = "PacMan1.png";
        flag=1;
    }
    }
</SCRIPT>
</head>
<body>

<img id="PacMan" src = "PacMan1.png" onClick=clearInterval(timer)
 style="position:absolute"> </img>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In x + interval you add interval always to zero; First get current div position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to move

```
var init=0;
var x = 0;
var dest_x = 800;
var interval = 10;
```

before `function Run(){`.

Now you overwrite results with initial data.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var timer = setInterval("Run()",500);
```

you missed some commas!

Comment: -1 for using eval notation. don't pass a string to that function.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read current pacMan position with

```
var x = img1.offsetLeft;
```

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, you have to make this using [Canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Tutorial/Basic_animations?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Canvas_tutorial/Basic_animations) (view the example on MDN) and JavaScript.

Comment: This is not an answer. Opinions go in the comment area.